# Python move to in-game X and Y?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, coordinates

I started Python a couple of weeks ago and I’d like to write a program that would be useful to myself.

I play a game that displays the in game X and Y (which is not the same as the screen X and Y)

I believe I know what to do but don’t know ‘how’ to do it.

I want to be able to type in X and Y coordinates and have the mouse direct me to said spot, I imagine I’d need a memory address of the in game coords and if statements to compare the user input to the current one in memory then move mouse and click in the appropriate direction?

Could someone provide an example that I can study or guide me to something made for this purpose?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is a very general question. In this forum it is very appreachiated if you show already the effort you have done to solve it on your own. Since you are a beginner I recommend that you search on beginners tutorials on Python programming including graphics. This might help: http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/), a cross-platform python module that can set the mouse position, as well as checking what it is at any given time. Examples  are on the other side of the link.

Comment: Wouldn’t this only go by the screen resolution X and Y?

Comment: If you got the position of the window and did some subtraction then no

Comment: By the way I would suggest using pygame or tkinter for this